# How to hide description from mobile version of blogger using css

Tags: css, blogger

I added a css code to hide blog description . but it does not apply for mobile version  .
Please help me ....

.header .description
{ display : none; }

Comment: Post a css related to your question

Comment: Your website might use media queries or even a separate .css file for the mobile version. A link to the page would be useful.

Comment: In order to help you, you should provide with a clearer description of what you are trying to achieve. A code snippet for example would be ideal. If you're looking to achieve mobile functionality please look into media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

First of all from your question alone it is not 100% clear exactly what you're looking to achieve; however it does pertain to hiding site content for mobile versions. The clearest CSS answer here is to use media queries. You can read about it anywhere, but as a demonstration you can also look at this code snippet I wrote for you

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Mobile first sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      Resize the window to see the blog description
      <div class="blog-description">
        You can only see me in Portrait Smartphones!
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.blog-description {
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  .blog-description {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

For more reference about media queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

I hope it helps!